Dispatching generic calls and types in TypeScript
I'm not sure if this is an appropriate SE site for this question. I think it belongs here better that to StackOverflow, because it is not about a single particular problem, but if you think otherwise, feel free to redirect me to SO or another Stack.
This is an expanded version of my question at SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78929495/typescript-conditional-type-does-not-accept-value-even-when-all-branches-do 
This is not real code (yes, I know it is discouraged here), but assume that my program needs to somehow "connect" to both Windows and Linux computers. Most of the code handling connections will be common, but there will be small differences. Also, I have a connection class, that has most of members common for Windows and Linux, but some are different.
I want to write the common code not thinking about the differences, and separate platform-dependent code into separate functions.
Being a primarily C++ programmer, I came up with the following code:
type Win = "win"
type Linux = "linux"

type BaseConnection = {
    name: string
    // some more members
}

type WinAddConnection = {
    winData?: string
}

type LinuxAddConnection = {
    linuxData?: string
}

type AddConnection<T> = 
    T extends Win ? WinAddConnection :
    T extends Linux ? LinuxAddConnection :
    {}  // or never

type Connection<T> = BaseConnection & AddConnection<T>

function processWin(connection: Connection<Win>) {
    // Some complex code
    console.log("Win: ", connection.winData)
}

function processLinux(connection: Connection<Linux>) {
    // Some complex code
    console.log("Linux: ", connection.linuxData)
}

function processPlatformSpecific<T>(connection: Connection<T>) {
    if ("winData" in connection) {
        processWin(connection)
    } else if ("linuxData" in connection) {
        processLinux(connection)
    }
}

function run<T>(connection: Connection<T>) {
    console.log(connection.name)
    // Some more complex code involving only BaseConnection fields.
    processPlatformSpecific(connection)
    // This does not work :(
    // const x: Connection<T> = { name: "foo" }
}

const connection: Connection<Win> = { name: "foo", winData: "aa" }
run(connection)

Basically, it works and serves my purpose: the main code (run<T>) does not know which system it connects to, code working with different systems is in separate functions (and can be in separate modules), adding new systems is simple and straightforward. Probably there is a bit much of boilerplate in AddConnection and process, but that's something that can be lived with.
However, there are also some problems:
Firstly, I can not create Connection objects not knowing the type: const x: Connection<T> = { name: "foo" } does not compile (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78929495/typescript-conditional-type-does-not-accept-value-even-when-all-branches-do)
Secondly, the detection code in process<T> (by checking the existence of winData and linuxData) is not completely correct and overall clumsy: it will not work when the object has no winData and no linuxData fields (e.g. const connection: Connection<Win> = { name: "foo" }); also if I have several different classes (not only Connection),  then I will have to write custom detection code for each class. (AFAIU, the former is a principal limitation of Typescript: there is no type information in runtime, so it is not possible to detect in runtime whether { name: "foo" } is Connection<Win> or Connection<Linux>.) Both issues can be solved by adding a type field to base class:
type BaseConnection = {
    name: string
    connectionType: Win | Linux
}

and checking it in process<T>, but this is even more clumsy, especially if I have many different classes and functions to dispatch.
And overall the code has more boilerplate than I would wish it had. Maybe there is a completely different approach, not C++, but true Typescript-style?
